# What are some examples of routine human activity times for certain cultures/peopes that are based on the position of the sun?

Tags: the-sun, time

What are some examples of timekeeping that are based on the height/angle/position of the sun. Two examples that come to mind are the times of the Islamic prayers times and the golden hour in photography.

Comment: Islamic prayers are not routine for 90% of humanity, golden hour is a description, not a routine.

Comment: I guess the title of the question could have been better. I really want to know when some people (besides astronomers/scientists) care about a particular position of the sun.  In other words are there any cultures/peoples for whom the physical position of the sun is important? Modern society seems to not care which is why I'm drawing blanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me now, and I didn't see a problem before either.

Comment: Watching the sunset with a margarita in your hand.

Comment: By "position of the sun" are you referring to daily positions ... or seasonal positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect farmers in many countries still plant and harvest their crops based on the suns position in the sky.

Answer (score 1):

We are now dependent for timekeeping on clocks, most clocks are synced (directly or indirectly) to atomic clocks that keep time without direct reference to the sun.

However, the principal definition of clock time, UTC, is coordinated to the position of the sun, through the insertion of leap seconds every 18 months or so. So anything that happens at a particular time is coordinated to the position of the sun, though not directly.

Comment: That is a good point. I thought of the 24 hour clock as completely artificial, but at the end of the day it is rooted in the actual position of the sun.